# VBA copy.range dont understand why is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple need to copy range from one sheet to another and I can do it differently, but I want to understand why this code dont work. Please, could you explain ?

```
Sub cioy()    
    Dim wb As Workbook    
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet    
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet   
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("sh1")    
    Set sh2 = wb.Sheets("sh2")  
    sh2.Cells.ClearContents    
    sh1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(12, 8)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Range(Cells(1, 1))    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is into cells(1,1) and cells(12,8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because [`Range()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range) property of `Worksheet` object would accept two `Range` parameters (the starting and ending range references of the wanted range) while you're giving only one (`Range(Cells(1, 1)`).

so you would code:

```
sh1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(12, 8)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Cells(1, 1)
```

or:

```
sh1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(12, 8)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("A1")
```

what above should fix the error

---

also, be aware that without an explicit `Sheet` reference, a `Range` object would implicitly take it as `ActiveSheet`, so your code would be the same as:

```
sh1.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 8)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Cells(1, 1)
```

which may not be what you need if `sh1` isn't the currently *Active* `sheet`.

hence you would more properly write:

```
sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(1, 1), sh1.Cells(12, 8)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Cells(1, 1)
```

or:

```
Range(sh1.Cells(1, 1), sh1.Cells(12, 8)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Cells(1, 1)
```

where you can notice you can omit the outer sheet reference, since using qualified `Range` references as parameters of a `Range` property leads the returned `Range` reference the same sheet as that of the two parameters ones

finally you could avoid all that burden by using the `Range(string address, string address)` notation of Range property and simply code:

```
sh1.Range("A1:H12").Copy Destination:=sh2.Cells(1, 1)
```

or:

```
sh1.Range("A1:H12").Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess the main reason was that I didnt use explicit sheet reference. Now I get it and code works perfectly. 
Also I like using cells more than string adresses because It seems easier for me to make dynamic references using lastrows / lastcolumns. It seems easier to read also than "A" & lastrow, idk. Anyway big thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Qualify your ranges with parent sheet name and you don't need Range wrapping Cells at end

```
Public Sub cioy()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets("sh1")
    Set sh2 = wb.Worksheets("sh2")

    sh2.Cells.ClearContents

    With sh1
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(12, 8)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Cells(1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My problem was that I didnt use explicit sheets references. Now I get the mechanics a little bit better